# Do Strongloop loopback app by default uses multiple processes?

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have created a loopback.io project which creates rest API of a MySQL table which contains more than 150,000 records, the rest API takes 30 seconds to retrieve specific(3) columns, I also have more two tables which are also big like this table, after combining these all the rest will go too slow.. Now I have 4 questions

1. Is this loopback project bydefault uses multiple process/threads?
2. If I have to separately do this step (i.e. process management) then how I will do it? (I have gone through documentation I am confused...)
3. is Strongloop Process Manager free for commercial use?
4. What should I do to increase the performance of REST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for question 1:
default is one per cpu

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Clustering

for question 2

$ slc ctl set-size your-app-name 2

2 being the number off processes you want

for question 3
yes,

strong-pm uses a dual license model.

You may use this library under the terms of the Artistic 2.0 license, or under the terms of the StrongLoop Subscription Agreement.

Question 4 requires more detail. perhaps is should be a separate question?